# Ubuntu 15.04 Nvidia drivers and break things /odd bugs-tearing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04

I have after many installs and reinstall's removed my gtx770 and my system works flawlessly. It seems as soon as I install any nvidia drivers (propitiatory or xorg) I have instability with the system. The original drivers Ubuntu setup leaves me with are just not cutting it, there is tearing and what I will say for lack of a better term glitches.

This is the case regardless of desktop environment with these issues.

There must be something I can do to correct this.